# Use function within module.exports that requires module variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am trying to avoid requiring more than once and so I am designing all of my modules to take arguments from the main `app.js` file. I have a module for users to login that looks like this:

```
module.exports = (express, router, jwt, user, config) => {
  function jwtSignUser (user) {
    const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    return jwt.sign(user, config.authentication,jwtSecret, {
      expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
    })
  }
  router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    const result = user.findOne(
      {
        email: req.body.email   
      },
      function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err)
        }
        console.log(user)
        res.send({
          user: user,
          token: jwtSignUser(user)
        })
      }
    )
  })
  return router
}
```

But when I try to run it I get an error `TypeError: jwtSignUser is not a function`

How can I use this function but still have the module take in the arguments necessary for the function (like jwt)? Is there a better way I can structure this? I am a newbie to Javascript

Comment: What exact line is the error on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to waste your time. I just didn't see the error when I posted.

Comment: One thing that could be messing you up is that you have three separate parameters named `user`, one is a parent that is hidden by the lower scoped ones.  It would be more clear and less prone to errors if you change the top scoped `user` to some other name and then it will be 100% clear in your code which one you mean to refer to.  Also, it seems like the top-scoped one is `userDB` or `userCollection` or something like that, not a single user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the "best" way to do this. But I did some re-factoring and got it to work by doing the following:

```
var jwtSignUser = (jwt, config, user) => {
  const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  return jwt.sign(user, config.authentication.jwtSecret, {
    expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
  })
}

var main = (express, router, jwt, user, config) => {
  router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    const result = user.findOne(
      {
        email: req.body.email   
      },
      function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err)
        }
        console.log(user)
        res.send({
          user: user,
          token: jwtSignUser(jwt, config, user.toObject())
        })
      }
    )
  })
  return router
}

module.exports = main
```

## Update

This is not the true reason for why this code now works. There is a part where I have `config.authentication,jwtSecret` which should be `config.authentication.jwtSecret`. It now seems to work regardless of where I stick the jstSignUser function

Comment: What exactly do you think fixed it?  An answer isn't particularly useful as a reference on stack overflow without knowing what the cause of the error was.  I see you are passing `user.toObject()` to `jwtSignUser()` this time instead of just `user`.  I'm not sure there's any functional difference besides that.  You still have the confusing two levels of `user` defined which you really should avoid.

Comment: It is clearly a scope issue. Did you downvote my question?

Comment: How is it a scope issue?  `jwtSignUser()` is accessible just fine in either of the two locations you show.  If it's clearly a scope issue, then please describe what the scope issue is.  So, far all it appears you've done is change one line of code and move a function and you have no idea what fixed what.  For your own benefit, you should understand why it works better than you have described so far.

Comment: It blows my mind that an individual trying to "help" can be so hostile and negative. You edited your rude and abusive comment into a question above my comment where I apologized politely. Unfortunately I do not have the time to sit here with baited breath waiting for a reply. I solved the problem on my own, no thanks to you, and now you feel it necessary to have me answer your question? Open up a new ticket.

Comment: And for the record, I am genuinely curious as to why this issue occurs, but I don't have the experience to be able to answer it. All I know is that in the original code the function was not found when called upon, and now it is. Looking at it again, I wonder if it would work if I were to embed it within the router post method.

Comment: I didn't edit my comments.  I removed my first comment based on your explanation.  When people who are trying to help you post comments asking questions about your question, it is your responsibility here to answer them.  Is there a reason you ignored them?  One use for downvotes on questions are for unclear questions where the author does not respond to attempts to clarify the question via comments. I would have liked to have helped you figure out what was really going on here, but you wouldn't engage. Without an ability to actually run and debug your code, we just have to ask questions. Bye.

Comment: Well unfortunately I wasn't in a position to reply instantly to you. Normally I would, but life sometimes deals you some shitty cards. I didn't ignore your questions either, I didn't even notice that you had added any. If you didn't edit your comment than you must have posted in between me typing a reply.

Comment: In case you didn't know, there's an inbox notification indicator in the upper right of every stack overflow window (I see it as the 5th glyph from the right edge in the upper ribbon bar).  That changes color when there's a comment to you or a comment on your question or answer that you haven't seen yet and it stays that color until you click on it.  You really can't miss a comment directed at you unless you don't visit the site or ignore that indicator.  It retains the recent comments directed at you too, even after you've viewed it.

Comment: I know life can sometimes get in the way, but from my perspective, we continued to converse and you never responded to those questions.  I guess you just never saw them (nothing I can do about that), but you can hopefully see why I felt like you were being non-responsive.  In order to use this site effectively, you need to not miss comments directly on your own question.  We worked on this over the course of more than an hour.

Comment: I am aware of the inbox notification indicator. Just ain't looking at that when I suddenly have to drive somebody to the hospital.